# Systrace on Android 4.3

Tags: android, systrace

I'm trying to measure performance attributes of my app through systrace by using the new [Trace API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Trace.html) introduced in JB 4.3. The idea is similar to the use of traceview method profiling, i.e. you can measure a specific code section using `Trace.beginSection` and `Trace.endSection`.

However, when I run systrace through the python script provided in Android tools, I don't see anything relating to the sections specified by the above calls.

Am I missing something? Is this the correct way of accessing the systrace output? I see in the documentation for the Trace calls that it "Writes trace events to the system trace buffer", but I have no idea how to access the trace buffer.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to provide an additional argument to the systrace command: `-app=pkgname` (or `-a pkgname`) where, `pkgname` is the package name from your app manifest.  It's also the name you see in the `ps` output (which is possibly more relevant, since that's what it's matching against).

There is an [example here](http://bigflake.com/systrace/).