# How to add some private trace elements on Systrace?

Tags: android, systrace

I`m trying to add some private trace elements to analyze them after gathering trace log by systrace.
To solve it, I read about [Systrace on Android 4.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18106123/systrace-on-android-4-3), but it is only the solution on App layer using java, right?
Is it possible to add more trace elements in kernel level?

Same question is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28080582/android-systrace-add-custom-kernel-traces ..

Someone help me to solve it...

Comment: The provided same question is not available anymore. And what do you mean by "private trace elements"?